# Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2020/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I ran into this issue when installing a theme and tried the two below without luck, any idea?

Change the right to 777
[image]

Modify the wp-config
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try once by putting the following code into `wp-config.php`

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Hope it will work for you. You can also read more [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#override-of-default-file-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Below method worked for me:
Making the webserver the owner of the wordpress folder recursively.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me :

From your Wordpress dashboard go to `Settings->Media` and set

`"Store uploads in this folder"` to `"wp-content/uploads"`